# Add prefix to filename on "Save Blender File"

Tags: python, add-on

I want a prefix added to the name of the .blend file when saved through the "Save" File Browser. 
Generating the prefix and new filename is no problem, but actually using the new filename is what i need help with.
So, what i want, if possible, is to "hook" into the "Save Blender File" button (or similar) to change the name of the .blend file when it is saved.
I want this to be done through a python addon.

Comment: from your question I can't get how it is related to "python" and "add-on" tags you selected..?

Comment: @MrZak Op said prefix. Also numerical increments are very simple and limited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Saving the blend file is performed by the `bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()` operator. This operator accepts a filepath which makes it easy to save the current blend file using a new filename. A simple operator can be created that calculates the new filename and then passes that to the standard file save.

While there is no easy way to alter the file menu without altering blender's bundled scripts, we can add an item to the file menu and disable the existing shortcuts so that the custom save operator will be used.

**Edit:** I thought this would be more complete if the user can specify a python string that calculates the prefix instead of having to alter the script. I have also included a helper function to easily include a formatted timestamp with `timestamp().strftime()`

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Save File Prefix",
    "author": "sambler",
    "version": (1,0),
    "blender": (2, 71, 0),
    "location": "File->Save Prefixed Blendfile",
    "description": "Add a prefix to the filename before saving.",
    "warning": "Runs user specified python code",
    "wiki_url": "https://github.com/sambler/addonsByMe/blob/master/file_prefix.py",
    "tracker_url": "https://github.com/sambler/addonsByMe/issues",
    "category": "System",
}

import bpy
import os
import time, datetime

class PrefixSavePreferences(bpy.types.AddonPreferences):
    bl_idname = __name__

    prefix = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Prefix calculation",
                    description="Python string that calculates the file prefix.",
                    default="timestamp().strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S') + '_'")

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column()

        row = col.row()
        row.prop(self,"prefix")

def timestamp():
    # convienience function that is available to the user in their calculations
    return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.time())

def fn_prefix(context):
    user_preferences = context.user_preferences
    addon_prefs = user_preferences.addons[__name__].preferences
    return eval(addon_prefs.prefix)

class PrefixFileSave(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Set a filename prefix before saving the file"""
    bl_idname = "wm.save_prefix"
    bl_label = "Save Prefixed Blendfile"

    def execute(self, context):
        outname = fn_prefix(context) + bpy.path.basename(bpy.data.filepath)
        outpath = os.path.dirname(bpy.path.abspath(bpy.data.filepath))
        print(os.path.join(outpath, outname))
        return bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile(filepath=os.path.join(outpath, outname),
                    check_existing=True)

def menu_save_prefix(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(PrefixFileSave.bl_idname, text=PrefixFileSave.bl_label, 
                icon="FILE_TICK")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

    # add the menuitem to the top of the file menu
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file.prepend(menu_save_prefix)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    win_keymaps = wm.keyconfigs.user.keymaps.get('Window')
    if win_keymaps:
        # disable standard save file keymaps
        for kmi in win_keymaps.keymap_items:
            if kmi.idname == 'wm.save_mainfile':
                kmi.active = False

        # add a keymap for our save operator
        kmi = win_keymaps.keymap_items.new(PrefixFileSave.bl_idname, 'S', 
                    'PRESS', ctrl=True)

def unregister():

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    win_keymaps = wm.keyconfigs.user.keymaps.get('Window')
    if win_keymaps:
        for kmi in win_keymaps.keymap_items:
            # re-enable standard save file
            if kmi.idname == 'wm.save_mainfile':
                kmi.active = True
            if kmi.idname == PrefixFileSave.bl_idname:
                win_keymaps.keymap_items.remove(kmi)

    bpy.types.INFO_MT_file.remove(menu_save_prefix)

    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```