# Extension of standard operator

Tags: python, operator

How can I add additional code for already existing operator? For example, I want to add into *bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile* this string:

```
print("My code")
```

I know that I can override this operator by creating a custom one with similar *bl_idname*, but previous features (saving functions in this example) will be destroyed too.

Hope for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after many time of research I found a quite enough answer on my question. I rephrased what I want and made the following things.

### Custom operator

First I created a custom operator. It looks like this:

```
class SaveFile(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my_wm.save"
    bl_label = "Save My File"

    def __init__(self):
        print("It is working now")

    def execute(self, context):
        try:
            bpy.ops.wm.save_mainfile()
            print("My code!")
        except RuntimeError:
            print("ERROR: Can't save file!")

        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return self.execute(context)
```

After that I registered it:

```
bpy.utils.register_class(SaveFile)
```

### Invocation

In the places, where I want to execute my custom code, I use this:

```
bpy.ops.my_wm.save()
```

Hope that it will be helpful for somebody else.

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40495/935) of interest. I would recommend naming it `wm.my_save`. Also store the return from the original save and respond to it, it may return [`{'CANCELLED'}`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.ops.html) and then you may not want to do your steps. An exception is thrown if there is an error, a user clicking cancel isn't an error.

Answer (score -3):

try to Going back.to ,>mainfile>findfilefolder>
/export// mainfile..<
/<
~resavefolder:>
(i hope this helps you.)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't understand what do you mean. I'm talking about the thing similar to function overloading in C++ but in python script.