# Blender kiosk mode?

Tags: python, customization, command-line

Sorry if the question is stupid or doesn't make sense. I'm playing around wiht Blender as a programmer, I'm not an 3d artist.

Is there a way to open Blender in this kiosk mode (like Electron does with Chrome) and create a custom UI, Menus, draw objects, etc. from python scripts? Like using Blender powerfull engine to build 3D apps or interactive experiences.

Thanks!

Comment: Kiosk mode (as in: one application the user is able to see and cannot access anything outside of it) would be something that has to be configured through the OS. Blender's UI is customizable through Python add-ons and you can create all kinds of amazing extended features. However Blender was **not** designed to be used as a building block or toolkit for custom interactive 3D applications, in the sense that you would start with zero functionality and add features in piece by piece from your toolbox. Therefore your ideas may require more work than you anticipate.

Comment: Blender does offer you the ability to create custom app templates and modify nearly everything through the Python API though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [`window_fullscreen_toggle`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.window_fullscreen_toggle) and [`screen_full_area()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.screen.html#bpy.ops.screen.screen_full_area). You can save a script in a blend file that will be [run when opening the file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/36822/935). If this is saved into the startup.blend, it will run each time you start blender.

An addon can create custom panels and menus as well as append and delete from existing menus. See [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40495/935) which adds a custom save to the file menu.

Depending on your goals, you can save a startup.blend with workspaces setup your way, you can ship this in your distribution with a [local config setup](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/advanced/blender_directory_layout.html).

The [blenderkit addon](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/BA/browse/master/blenderkit/) ships with blender and does some custom drawing in the viewport, where you can drag and drop its items.

CGCookies [Retopoflow](https://blendermarket.com/products/retopoflow) is an example of adding a custom UI inside the viewport.

At the extreme end, you can make a custom build with your UI scripts. See the [Fluid Designer demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6UD5C5UU7Pk) as an example.